# How do I disable Chrome Developers Toolkit (Tools)

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Chrome seems to have gotten really slow in the last few months (for me) if I have more than about 8 or 10 tabs open (spread among a few windows).

I'm wondering if it's Chrome Developer Tools. 
It normally prompts me to disable those but naturally, as soon as I thought "that might be the cause" I'm not seeing that option.

Is there a way to manually disable those tools?

Comment: I can't imagine that the developer tools would be causing a slowdown, if they're not active. Although, I agree that Chrome has been slowing my system down lately as well. My solution was to download an extension called "Context". It lets you set up profiles for your extentions, so you can setup groups of extensions based on your current browsing needs. For example, I have the following profiles "All", "Shopping", "Surfing", "Dev", and "Minimal". I've found it helps a lot, because I don't always have a dozen extensions running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DevTools cannot be disabled (other than through an administrative policy, see [Google chrome develop tools disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726308/google-chrome-develop-tools-disabled), but it does not actually remove the code :) - you will just be unable to inspect your pages), and they consume infinitesimal amounts of your computer resources when inactive.