# can't open chrome developer tool

Tags: google-chrome

Today, Chrome Developer Tool suddenly can't open, press F12 have no reaction, the menu is grey 
Unstall and installed ver 45 or 47, won't open

My system is Win7(x64), I try to open Regedit, and can't find "DeveloperToolsDisabled", and type "chrome://policy/" in url bar, can see DeveloperToolsDisabled is true

[screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOjpi.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google chrome develop tools disabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726308/google-chrome-develop-tools-disabled)

Comment: Also a [question on super user](http://superuser.com/questions/696770/chrome-developer-tools-disabled) with a different solution.