# Google Chrome argument to block developer tools

Tags: google-chrome

I'm looking for an argument to pass to Google Chrome to prevent users to press F12 and enter developer tools to perform Javascript injections (the app must be run from only 1 terminal). I've found [this list](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) but there isn't any mention of it. Does an argument like this exist?

Thank you.

Comment: I very much doubt that exist. Would just be hugely annoying, and get abused by the same dumb people who thought “right click disabled”-alerts were a sensible thing to do a decade ago ... _“to prevent users [...] to perform Javascript injections”_ - then implement CSP properly.

Comment: I doubt it as well, but I just wanted to be sure. CSP is already implemented properly but adding an extra security measure wouldn't have hurt. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google chrome develop tools disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726308/google-chrome-develop-tools-disabled)

Comment: @JoshLee nope, I'm looking for an argument for opening Chrome from command line, not a registry key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only command line flag that disables the developer tools is `--kiosk`, so you'd have to be willing to live with the other features that kiosk mode removes (which it sounds like you are). Otherwise you need to configure the policy.

Comment: I was aware of kiosk mode but I didn't know it would also disable developer tools. That was exactly what I was looking for, thank you.